# How do I make a class take precedence over an id?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="normal" class="wider">

</div>
```

But this doesn't work! The blah's width till cancels out class "wider"'s with.

Comment: Huh? Please be more explicit in your example.

Comment: I suspect he wants the width declared for `.wider` to take precedence over the one declared for `#normal`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you have there is a [CSS specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) problem.

`.wider` has a specificity of `0,0,1,0` while `#normal` has `0,1,0,0`. You can't beat an ID with anything else than an ID (or inline definitions, but that is not the case here).

What I would recommend, if you cannot put the needed `width` declaration in the `#normal` selector, is to put it in `#normal.wider` or, if that either isn't possible, have an identified container, say `#container`, as high in the hierarchy as possible (maybe an ID on the body?) and replace `.wider` with `#container .wider`. This new selector will have a specificity of `0,1,1,0` which is a bit higher than `0,1,0,0`.

Using `!important` will work too, but it should be used only as a last resort.

Example:

```
<div id="container" class="wrapper">
    <div id="normal" class="wider">
</div>
```

For this HTML snippet some possible selectors in decreasing order of specificity would be:

```
CSS Selector         -> Specificity
---------------------------------------
#container #normal   -> 0,2,0,0
#container .wider    -> 0,1,1,0 // These two have the same specificity so
#normal.wider        -> 0,1,1,0 // the last declared value will be used
#normal              -> 0,1,0,0
.wrapper .wider      -> 0,0,2,0
.wider               -> 0,0,1,0
```

Answer (score 3):

use #blah.wider instead to solve this

Answer (score 3):

You can decorate attributes with `!important` to increase their...importance.

```
.wider
{
    width:9000px !important;
}
```

Comment: A note: You don't increase or decrease the importance. You just *make them important*. You can't make them double important. By making them important you say that they take precedence over those that are not important, but the means of deciding which of two declarations that are both either important or not important is called specificity and it's determined by the structure of the selector.

Comment: A good point. And there's even more to it than that -- a style's origin affects it as well. For example, user important styles override author important styles, regardless of specificity. I used the word importance vaguely to mean what I suppose could be better called the cascading precedence.

Answer (score 0):

As people have already mentioned, an ID has a specificity of 100, whereas a class has only 10.

An alternative to answers suggested (that doesn't use `!important`,) is to remove the property from `#normal` that's conflicting (the width,) and apply it to a second class.  So it'd look like:

```
#normal {
     padding : 0;
     margin : 0;
}

.normal {
     width : 400px;
}

.wider {
     width : 1000px;
}
```

Leaving your actual markup to be:

```
<div id="normal" class="normal"> 
</div>
```

where you want the 'normal width,' and:

```
<div id="normal" class="wider">
</div>
```

Where you want the extra wide element.  You may have to go back through your pages that use `#normal` to add the `.normal` class, but this will fix your problem.

I also think Gerben's answer works too--adds 10 more specificity to the ID property (totally 110,) which should override the `#normal` width property.

```
#normal.wider {
     1000px;
}
```

Comment: An ID doesn't actually have a specificity of 100 and class one of 10, that's just a common analogy to make people understand. They have specificities of 0,1,0,0 and 0,0,1,0 respectively. The fact that in most cases you can compute using 100 and 10 is due to people not using more than 9 IDs or classes. Note that 11 classes still have lower specificity than a single ID. If you want to be rigorous you have to use the `a,b,c,d` notation.

Comment: Boom. Alin has spoken ;) Thanks, I think I have a better understanding of CSS specificity.

Answer (score 0):

256 CSS Classes Can Override an #id: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lzjqh

Alin Purcaru's answer explains the basic rules of css precedence calculation. But the explanation of the implementation could be found at http://hackerne.ws/item?id=4388649