# Difference between div#test and #test in CSS

Tags: css

Is there a difference between div#test and #test selector in CSS?

How does it help to add 'div' before the id? Which method is recommended?

Comment: One looks for `<div id="test">`, the other looks for `<* id="test">`, where `*` is any tag. That's it. Any performance different is negligible. I recommend to use `#test` because the `div` part is just needless extra info which must be evaluated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
#test
```

to specify a rule for any element with the **single unique id**, 'test'. There is **always** one unique id on 1 page.

If your stylesheet is **shared** between multiple HTML documents where the id test can have different meanings like

```
div#test OR p#test
```

declare the tagname as well.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from `div#test` only matching `<div>` elements, it also has a higher specificity than `#test`, so where you have the following code:

```
div#test { color: green; }
#test { color: red; }
```

... the colour of `#test` would be green, assuming it is a `<div>` element.  However, specificity isn't normally required with ID selectors, since they're required to be unique, unless there is a possibility it may move between ancestors or may be applied to different elements.

In summary, use `#test` if the element will always be a static `<div>`.

**See also:**

- [Calculating a selector's specificity - w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)
- [CSS Specificity (HTML Dog)](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/)

Comment: I question if the specifity-score between div#test and #test is 1. eg: what is the difference in <div><div id="test"></div> between div#test AND div>#test then ? 0 or 1 or .5? (just thinking, still agree your statement)

Comment: @Caspar: in that case, the specificity score is equal between both selectors and the order comes into play, where the latest defined selector takes precedence.

Comment: order. indeed  (forgot that ;)

Answer (score 2):

div#test only matches div elements with id 'test', #test matches any element with the id 'test'.

Answer (score 1):

`div#test` matches a *div* with the id="test". `#test` is matching *any element* with the id="test". Id's are basically stored in a hashtable/index and are direct lookups; it's not necessary to qualify them with an element.

So I would suggest sticking with #test.

Answer (score 1):

Taken and slightly modified from [How do I make a class take precedence over an ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702328/how-do-i-make-a-class-take-precedence-over-an-id/4702475#4702475)

```
<div id="container" class="wrapper">
    <div id="normal" class="wider">
</div>
```

For this HTML snippet some possible selectors in decreasing order of specificity would be:

```
CSS Selector         -> Specificity
---------------------------------------
#container #normal   -> 0,2,0,0
#container .wider    -> 0,1,1,0
#normal.wider        -> 0,1,1,0
div#normal           -> 0,1,0,1 // this is the case you're asking about
#normal              -> 0,1,0,0
.wrapper .wider      -> 0,0,2,0
.wider               -> 0,0,1,0
```

Since ID's are unique (per page,) you're getting into esoteric CSS where you'd ever need to worry about the difference between `div#test` and `#test`--as Caspar Kleijne mentioned, a CSS document for multiple pages is probably the most likely scenario.

`div.test` vs. `.test` is a more likely scenario however, since you'll be able to wield class specificity much easiest on any given page.