# Italics font-style not working on element's class attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a simple exercise: changing `font-style` by associating an element with a `class`.

### Code Snippet

```js
var divAdvert = document.getElementById("divAdvert");
divAdvert.className = "newStyle";
```

```css
#divAdvert {
  font: 12pt arial;
}
.newStyle {
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="divAdvert">Here is an advertisement</div>
```

The above resulted in 'Here is an advertisement' with underline but without italic font style.

However, italic works if I included `font-style: italic;` under `#divAdvert`

Why is that?

Comment: The `font` style on the ID takes precedence over the `font-style` style on the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined `font` property of *CSS* using `#divAdvert` and it gets preference over your `.newStyle` that has only `font-style` so if you want to add/alter any sub-property in *CSS* you need to define as my code snippet below:

### Code Snippet

```js
var divAdvert = document.getElementById("divAdvert");
divAdvert.className = "newStyle";
```

```css
#divAdvert {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
.newStyle {
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="divAdvert">Here is an advertisement</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this link will help you and give you another explanation for your problem 
[How do I make a class take precedence over an id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702328/how-do-i-make-a-class-take-precedence-over-an-id)

What you have there is a http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity problem.

`.wider` has a specificity of `0,0,1,0` while `#normal` has `0,1,0,0`. You can't beat an ID with anything else than an ID (or inline definitions, but that is not the case here).

What I would recommend, if you cannot put the needed `width` declaration in the `#normal` selector, is to put it in `#normal.wider` or, if that either isn't possible, have an identified container, say `#container`, as high in the hierarchy as possible (maybe an ID on the body?) and replace `.wider` with `#container .wider`. This new selector will have a specificity of `0,1,1,0` which is a bit higher than `0,1,0,0`.

Using `!important` will work too, but it should be used only as a last resort.

Example:

```
<div id="container" class="wrapper">
<div id="normal" class="wider">
</div>
```

For this HTML snippet some possible selectors in decreasing order of specificity would be:

```
    CSS Selector         -> Specificity
---------------------------------------
#container #normal   -> 0,2,0,0
#container .wider    -> 0,1,1,0 // These two have the same specificity so
#normal.wider        -> 0,1,1,0 // the last declared value will be used
#normal              -> 0,1,0,0
.wrapper .wider      -> 0,0,2,0
.wider               -> 0,0,1,0
```

Comment: do you mean like this  @eisbehr

Comment: This doesn't seem to really answer the question. You say *"`.wider` has a specificity of`0,0,1,0` while `#normal` has `0,1,0,0`"*. But there's no `wider` or `normal` in the question.

Comment: this is the answer of the question mentioned @Pang